# Rails 3.1 - what is the best way to access controllers' variables in coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I am looking for a recipe to use the controller's global variables into a coffeescript like this :

Controller :

```
respond_to :js

def create
  @commentable = commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build({:comment => params[:comment], :user => current_user})
  @comment.save
  respond_with(@comment, @commentable)
end
```

create.js.coffee :

```
$("#form_#{@commentable.class}_#{@commentable.id}").hide()
```

The idea is to have several commentables in a single page and to identify the one which is currently commented to hide/show a form to comment it ; the form's id is built using the class and the id of the commentable. At this time, if I try to access an element with the code above, it does not work because @commentable does not seem to exist in the script.

**EDIT:**

I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506963/how-to-access-controllers-variables-in-app-assets-files/6527684#6527684), and I tried the following :

In my posts/show.haml

```
:javascript
  var commentable_comments_id;
#post
  @post.body
= render :partial => 'comments/list', :locals => {:commentable => @post}
```

In my partial _list.haml

```
#comments_container
  %div{:id => "comments_#{commentable.class}_#{commentable.id}"}
    - commentable.comments.reverse_each do |comment|
      = render :partial => 'comments/comment', :locals => {:comment => comment}
  - if current_user
    .add_comment_link{:id => "link_#{commentable.class}_#{commentable.id}"}
      #{link_to "Commenter"}
    .add_comment{:id => "form_#{commentable.class}_#{commentable.id}"}
      = render :partial => 'comments/comment_form', :locals => {:commentable => commentable}
```

And in the partial _comment_form.haml

```
.comment_form
  = form_tag polymorphic_path([commentable, Comment]) , :method => :post, :remote => true do |f|
    .comment_field
      = text_area_tag :comment, params[:comment], :id =>"comment_area", :rows => 4, :cols => 50
    .comment_field 
      = submit_tag "Commenter", :id => "submit_comment_#{commentable.class}_#{commentable.id}", :class => "submit_comment"
```

In the posts.js.coffee :

```
jQuery ->

  commentable_link_id = null
  commentable_form_id = null

  hide_element_by_id = (id_name) ->
    $("#"+id_name).hide()
  show_element_by_id = (id_name) ->
    $("#"+id_name).show()

  $('.add_comment_link').click ->
    currentId = $(this).attr('id')
    if(commentable_link_id != null && commentable_form_id != null)
      hide_element_by_id(commentable_form_id)
      show_element_by_id(commentable_link_id)

    commentable_link_id = currentId
    commentable_form_id = currentId.replace("link", "form")    
    hide_element_by_id(commentable_link_id)
    show_element_by_id(commentable_form_id)

    commentable_comments_id = currentId.replace("link", "comments")   
    false

  $('.submit_comment').click -> 
    if(commentable_link_id != null && commentable_form_id != null)
      hide_element_by_id(commentable_form_id)
      show_element_by_id(commentable_link_id)
```

So when the user click on the link to add a comment, it hides the previous comment form (if any), it shows the new correct one, builds the id of the comments'container (for example comments_Post_3) and store it in a global js variable of the page :

```
commentable_comments_id = currentId.replace("link", "comments")
```

Then in the create.js.coffee, I try to append the new comment in the stored container using this variable :

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment))%>')
  .appendTo("#"+commentable_comments_id)
  .hide()
  .fadeIn()
```

I think this is not correct because the last operation (the append with fading) is not working, so the global variable commentable_comments_id must not be initialized or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [coffeebeans](https://github.com/markbates/coffeebeans).

Just add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'coffeebeans'
```

And then create the file as you want:

```
#app/views/posts/create.js.coffee
$("#form_<%= @commentable.class %>_<%= @commentable.id %>").hide()
```

Comment: This is great, it works exactly as I expected to. Just one thing : the code above does not work in my case, because the id to identify was in the the format `#form_Post_3`, so I needed to use `$("#form_<%= @commentable.class %>_<%= @commentable.id %>").hide()`, without the `#{}`.

Comment: To make it work on Heroku, I needed to add the gem 'therubyracer' in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use erb in your coffeescript files you have to append the erb extension to the file. So your file should be renamed to `create.js.coffee.erb`. And then you can do something like:

```
$ ->
  alert('<%= Post.first.name %>')
```

It should work fine. See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for further information.

**EDIT**

I think I've missed a point in your question. If you want to access instance variables in your js files, unfortunately **you can't**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527684/249630) answer for further information.

Comment: I edited the question with more precisions on what I tried to do after  reading your link. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: This is not true.  When submitting remote forms, you do not need to add the erb extension. Just ask samnang.  https://github.com/samnang/ajax_rails31_demo

Answer (score 0):

When you're responding to js it means it renders the `create.js.coffee` as a view. You **don't need** to add `.erb` to the end to use erb code inside, like this:

```
$("#form_<%=@commentable.class%>_<%=@commentable.id>").hide()
```

You are probably confused by the `@` in coffeescript, it just means `this.` or `this` in javascript. And the `#{ .. }` code is interpreted only by coffeescript not by ruby (as you're used to in HAML), so the code you have would output this in javascript:

```
$("#form_" + this.commentable["class"] + "_" + this.commentable.id).hide();
```